# Qt. undefined reference to '_time32'

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, include, linker-errors

I compiled static Qt with static OpenSSL and now get following errors while compiling my project:

`undefined reference to '_time32'`

`undefined reference to '_gmtime32'`

`undefined reference to '_localtime32'`

I think I should add something in .pro file. Any ideas?

*(compiler: TDM-GCC, os: win32)*

**SOLVED (see below)**

Comment: You may need to link with the time library. For gcc this is librt, linked with the -lrt option.

Comment: Where should I add this option? LIBS += -lrt?

Comment: if you're using the GNU make default rules then LDFLAGS+=-lrt

Comment: Did you use TDM-GCC to compile Qt too or did you use the mingw included with QtSDK ?

Comment: @Eddie: If your issue is solved, you should answer and then accept your own answer instead of editing your post with "SOLVED". Also, QT is not an acronym and is spelled Qt.

Comment: @Sosukodo. Ok, I will add the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution.**

I compiled Qt and my project with TDM-GCC, but MSYS used another MinGW (to compile OpenSSL). To solve the problem I added the file `C:\msys\etc\fstab` with the following line:

`c:/qt/mingw32 /mingw`

Qt, openSSL and my project have compiled successfully.

Comment: Now it's time to accept the answer if it solved your problem :-)

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know they did that. Thanks for the info.